# Get access token with appid and userid

Tags: facebook, rest

I have a facebook app. id and a facebook user id, I need to retrieve the access token for such a user. How could I do that?

Cheers.

Comment: Try it yourself and if you have problems explain where the problem is. Also add which language you are using and if you are using any libs.

Comment: Found this:  https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<APPID>&client_secret=<APPSECRET>&grant_type=client_credentials however it creates a auth token from a app-id and app-secret. I need to create auth token from appid and userid so the auth token can be stored for especific users.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ - you really should read all this

Comment: I already read it, however still don't see how to generate the access token by only using the app id and user id, found this sample but still not what I looking for : [link](http://www.richardnichols.net/2010/06/implementing-facebook-oauth-2-0-authentication-in-java/)

Comment: to get the accesstoken you have to be the user ! you can only get accesstoken if you do enter username password on Facebook Connect Login form

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to generate a user access token using simply an application id and secret you **must** go through a login flow.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/